# C ISR handlers in c++ application

Tags: c++, c, embedded, isr

I'm writing a C++ application on top of a C HAL for an embedded systems. I need to call an object method from a peripheral C handler but I'm having the following issue:

The peripheral ISR handler I pass to the HAL has a fixed signature. Because of that I can't pass a public method of a C++ object because of the implicit parameter this. In the handler I don't have any reference to the object.

One solution could be to make this object singleton to have a global acces to it but for any reason I may don't want it.

What can I do?

Comment: There is not much alternative to a static of one sort or another - a struct, int or 'this' instance pointer.  It's just kinda inherent in communcating with interrupt-handlers that have no process/thread context when they run:(

Comment: Does the ISR take a call back parameter as well as the function address ?  If so you could either pass `this` (suitably cast) and a static member function or a key to look up the class in an array/map.

Comment: @RichardCritten ISRs don't have parameters, since they are called by hardware not software.

Comment: You may want to list the reasons why you don't want to have a singleton so they can be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

A plain C++ member function can never be an ISR. It has to be a `static` member function. Indeed you have to do some manner of singleton design. There is no need to make anything "global" though.

This is not unique to ISRs but the same applies to any callback function.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to have a method pointer variable that is settable and the ISR calls that method pointer if it is set.

This is untested, uncompiled code, but shows how I would start:

```
void (*Object::Method)() IsrMethod;

// call this to set the method that will be called.  Maybe pass
// in the method pointer of a specific object.
void SetIsrMethod()
{
    IsrMethod= someObject.someMethod;
}

void ISR()
{
    // if the method is valid, call it.
    if( IsrMethod!= null )
    {
        IsrMethod();
    }
}
```

This also assumes that the object is valid and not deleted.

Comment: You cannot call a non-static member function through a member function pointer without also providing an object pointer.  That said it is the kernel of the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class MyObj
{
public:
    void doIsr()
    {
        // Handle ISR.
    }
    static void HandleIsr()
    {
        MyObj* isrObj = getRelevantObject();  // Whatever object you like to call to.
        isrObj.doIsr();
    }
}
```

If you want to register a specific object to the isr, you can do it like so:

```
Class MyObj
{
public:
    void doIsr()
    {
        // Handle ISR.
    }
    static void HandleIsr(MyObj* obj)
    {
        obj.doIsr();
    }
}
```

And when you register to the ISR, you need to pass `obj` as a parameter.